# Do db.session.query and models.ModelName.query use the same session?

Tags: postgresql, session, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my project I have some idle_in_transaction sessions the source of which I can't find.

I have custom base_query which is a child of the BaseQuery with the only modification being one additional `.filter()`.

It seems that `db.session.query` and `models.ModelName.query` use the same session (based on the `pg_stat_activity` table), but looking at the code of flask-sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy it is not obvious.

As far as I understood, `db.session` is a scoped session, and model query class uses default SQLAlchemy session.

Do they really use the same session? If not, this would explain why I have idle_in_transaction sessions